# How to create a Blob of a PDF file when you have the content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, pdf, blob

I was trying to get a Google Drive file's metadata using this [Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) and [Google File Picker](https://github.com/sdoomz/react-google-picker). After making a successful request(status 200) I got a response as:

[image: Snapshot of the response]

This is the raw response:

```js
{
  "gapiRequest":{
    "data":{
      "body":"%PDF-1.5\n%¿÷¢þ\n2....6\n%%EOF\n",
      "headers":{
        "cache-control":"private,max-age=0, must-revalidate",
        "content-encoding":"gzip",
        "content-type":"text/plain;charset=UTF-8",
        "date":"Wed, 05 Aug 2020 14:44:43 GMT",
        "expires":"Wed, 05 Aug 2020 14:44:43 GMT",
        "server":"UploadServer",
        "vary":"Origin, X-Origin",
        "x-guploader-uploadid":"AAANsUmkhdrrBAhb1C30yaK09LEZzu1BjYUmIAU9iI9J3lYXHih-4CUPFP6jDhC-sc-xveULFdcNJFp5oQhpQrgzluhWTSvrYg",
        "Content-Type":"application/pdf"
      },
      "status":200
     }
   }
 }
```

Next I created a Blob using the contents of the body i.e. `gapiRequest.data.body` and made a download link with that Blob but when I download it fails to load the PDF file. It says "Failed to load PDF"

My code is:

```js
var request = window.gapi.client.request({
   'path': `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileId}?alt=media`,
   'method': 'GET'
});
request.execute((json, raw) => {
   console.log('JSON: ', json, '\nRAW: ', JSON.parse(raw));
   var val = JSON.parse(raw).gapiRequest.data.body;
   var myBlob = new Blob([val], { type: 'application/pdf' })

    //making a downloadable link. 
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
    document.getElementById('download-file').href = url;
});
```

I am also linking the full code of App.js [here](https://pastebin.com/Z3bj9hs3)

Comment: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: use filereader and convert the filereader.result to blob data

Comment: @AshishMishra So I tried your approach, 
`var val = JSON.parse(raw).gapiRequest.data.body;
var reader = new FileReader();
var myBlob = new Blob([val], { type: 'application/pdf' });
reader.readAsBinaryString(myBlob);
console.log(reader.result);`
here the output of the console.log was blank. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It will be blank as the file is not loaded yet.

Comment: Try something like this-   `const reader = new FileReader(filepath);
reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
reader.onloadend = () => {
let base64 = reader.result;
fetch(base64).then(res => res.blob()).then((blobData) => {
//now you have the blobData`